# Android regexp HTML

Tags: android, html, regex

I've got a HTML code stored in string and I want to extract all parts that match the pattern, which is:

```
<a href="http://abc.pl/(.*?)/(.*?)"><img src="(.*?)"
```

`(.*?)` stands for any string. I've tried dozens of combinations and couldn't get it working. Can somebody show me a sample code, which extracts all matched data from a String and store it in variables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give an example of what output you expect.

Comment: An example showing how to loop through each (.*?) for every match will do, I can handle it from there.

Comment: But is this in JavaScript or in Java (in an Android app)?

Comment: Java. You write in Java for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's the sample:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("patternGoesHere");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textGoesHere);
while (matcher.find())
{
    // You can access substring here via matcher.group(substringIndex) [note they are indexed from 1, not 0]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using JavaScript. I hope this helps.

First, we need a working pattern:

```
var pattern = '<a href="http://abc.pl/([^/"]+)/([^/"]*)".*?><img src="([^"]*)"';
```

Now, the problem is that in JavaScript there is no native method or function that retrieves *both* all matches and all submatches at once, whatever the regexp we use.

We can easily retrieve an array of all the full matches:

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
var matches = yourHtmlString.match(re);
```

But we also want the submatches, right? In my humble opinion, the simplest way to achieve this is to apply the non-greedy version of the same regexp to each match we obtained (because only non-greedy regexes can return submatches):

```
var reNonGreedy = new RegExp(pattern);
var matchesAndSubmatches = [];
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    matchesAndSubmatches[i] = matches[i].match(reNonGreedy);
}
```

Each element of `matchesAndSubmatches` is now an array such that:

`matchesAndSubmatches[n][0]` is the `n`-th full match,
`matchesAndSubmatches[n][1]` is the first submatch of the `n`-th full match,
`matchesAndSubmatches[n][2]` is the second submatch of the `n`-th full match, and so on.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer, but I do know JavaScript and I know how the regular expression should look like. The problem is with Java part.